# Insert sum of the row data of each record into separate column in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table

```
   id   name     class  social  science math  Total
    2   Max      Three  85        56     85
    3   Arnold   Three  55        40     75
    4   Krish    Four   60        50     70
    5   John     Four   60        80     90
```

I have to find total of each student's marks and insert to column Total.

While running this query -

```
INSERT INTO student(Total)    
SELECT (social + math + science ) as Total from student;
```

I am getting in this format -

```
   id   name     class  social  science math  Total
    2   Max      Three  85        56     85
    3   Arnold   Three  55        40     75
    4   Krish    Four   60        50     70
    5   John     Four   60        80     90
    6                                          226
    7                                          170
    8                                          180
    9                                          230
```

How to correct this I am not getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `UPDATE` statement.

```
update student 
   set total = social + math + science;
```

But that column is totally useless. In general you should not store data in a database that can easily be derived from existing values.

In your, adding the values of the three columns adds no (noticeable) overhead to a select statement, so there is no point in storing the total.

You should rather remove the column completely and then create a view doing this for you. Otherwise you need to update that column each time one of the other three columns are changed.

```
create view total_score
as
select id, name, class, social, science, math, 
       social + math + science as total
from student;
```

---

Plus: your `name` column should be defined as `NOT NULL`.

Comment: "In general you should not store data in a database that can easily be derived from existing values"  ... if there are a large number of rows, and you want an index on that column for searching and sorting, then it's worthwhile to save the computed values

Comment: @glyph: or just create an index on the expression

Comment: That's why I said "large number of rows" where you may be concerned about a performance hit from having to compute expressions on the fly

Comment: The overhead of doing a sum like in the answer is pretty much negligible. The only reason with "a large number of rows"  to pre-compute this is, if you want to have a condition on the expression (e.g. `where social + math + science > 42`)  and for that an index on that expression is enough. No need to store it twice (once as a computed column and then again in the index on that column)